# Ruby not reading database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

```
$ vi database.yml
(Full database.yml contents)
development:
   encoding: unicode 
   adapter: postgresql 
   username: someuser 
   pool: 10  
   port: 5432  
   host: 10.55.333.222  <This is not a real IP address>
   database: myrailsapp  
   password: mypassword  
   min_messages: WARNING  

$ RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate <br />
(in /var/www/dress_rails_app) <br />
rake aborted! <br />
could not connect to server: Connection refused 
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting 
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432? <br />

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment <br />
(See full trace by running task with --trace) <br />
```

I am not trying to connect to (127.0.0.1/localhost).  I am trying to connect to the remote host but my database.yml is being ignored.  I am trying to connect to a postgresql remote host but my database.yml is being ignored and my ruby app continues to attempt to connect to the localhost.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
(in /var/www/dress_rails_app)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1206:in `connect'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:309:in `new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:319:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `block in checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:233:in `checkout'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:96:in `block in connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:404:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__486199626554910505__prepare__4301182059246596778__callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/dress_rails_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

This the output from validating the YAML in the database.yml file:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> db_yaml = YAML.load_file('/var/www/dress_rails_app/config/database.yml')
=> {"development"=>{"encoding"=>"unicode", "adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>10, "port"=>5432, "username"=>"someuser", "database"=>"dress_rails_app", "password"=>"somepassword", "host"=>"10.4.66.18"}}
irb(main):003:0> puts db_yaml.inspect
{"development"=>{"encoding"=>"unicode", "adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>10, "port"=>5432, "username"=>"someuser", "database"=>"dress_rails_app", "password"=>"somepassword", "host"=>"10.4.66.18"}}
=> nil
```

Comment: Hard to tell with your partial and edited database.yml, but it seems to be reading it since it's trying to connect to the port you specified, not the default MySQL port. Can you post the full database.yml file (with IP addresses and password redacted if required)?

Comment: @Thilo, that is the full database.yml, however, ruby is ignoring the file and trying to connect the localhost instead of the remote host.

Comment: @Thilo, also this is postgres not MySQL.

Comment: Doh - my bad. Not sure then. I assume you can connect to your server from the command line?

Comment: I used the config from your database.yml, and got `rake aborted!
could not translate host name "10.55.333.222" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` error message; so the content seems to be correct. Dumb question: Is the database.yml in the correct folder? The full path of the file would be `/var/www/dress_rails_app/config/database.yml`. From your comments above, it seems to be in the main folder as `/var/www/dress_rails_app/database.yml`

Comment: @prakash, yes the file is in /var/www/dress_rails_app/config/database.yml

Comment: @thilo, you were correct that it is reading the database.yml because I tried changing the port, but for some reason it is trying to connect to the local host verus the host: IP that is specified in the database.yml

Comment: did you change the IP address in the file to obfuscate it? since 10.55.333.222 isn't a valid IP Address.  also you can see what Rails is picking up the database by looking at Rails.configuration.database_configuration in the console

Comment: @Doon yes I did change the IP Address to to obfuscate it. Also, since the database.yml isn't working correctly, I am unable to access the Rails console.You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The database.yml looks correct but things I would try to verify it is.

Verify the yml is valid

```
require 'yaml'
db_yaml = YAML.load_file('/path/to/database.yml')
puts db_yaml.inspect
```

to make sure that you can read/parse it, and there aren't error tabs, etc.. in there.  I am using pretty much the same config on my staging servers and it works as expected

```
staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: staging_db
  username: doon
  password: my_password
  host: 172.20.0.99
```

Comment: I verified that the YAML was correct.  Please see the results above.

Comment: check permissions on the file?, make sure there is nothing in the initializers that messes with it? remove the pool and other statements so it is at bare minimum config). Sorry running out of ideas.

Comment: thanks for all of your help.  I am totally stumped by this.  All of your ideas were solid, but none of them worked.  The application is reading the yaml file but for some reason it tries to connect to the localhost versus the remote IP.  Unreal.  I have never seen anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

After debugging the postgresql_adapter in activerecord - I found the solution.
Inside database.yml, just replace `host: <ip address>`
with `hostname: <ip address>`